# How to print to a specific line in java.io.FileWriter

Tags: java, io, filewriter

How do you print to a certain line in the file? It is not included in the javadoc and I don't know how to do it (if you even can).

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: Might want to provide what you've attempted. There are ways to do it but you haven't shown any effort with any code

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way.

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("the file path...")));
    bw.write("anything you wanna write into the file");
```